# Double window has play when pushed on

Tags: windows

My son bought a house that has a window like this one.

[image]

When I push in the center from the inside, there is some play of a quarter of an inch or so at the bottom (and the top I presume). Maybe more. What does this mean? Was it not installed properly? Is there some part that needs nailing in the center? How difficult is the fix?

There is no caulk around it but the window is original, I think.

EDIT: The rumors of how much play is there were greatly exaggerated. The amount of give at the bottom and top of the window is just about 1/16-inch in the center. Still, is this too much?

Comment: What is the procedure to remove the window pane?  That may be related.

Comment: What is your climate? How important is it that the house be well-sealed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is, but it certainly doesn't sound right. It may be that you have a mulled window (here's a video about [mulled windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKTwbXP8s1o)), and perhaps the flanges were not nailed in or the nails missed the (rough) sill or header.

I think that the place to start would be to remove the siding under (and around) the window to get a better look at the problem. Here's a quick video about [working with vinyl siding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S82hxw5T88Q).

Comment: I finally had a chance to look at the windows again and, yes, they are mulled, a term I never heard of before. I'm getting ready to try and remove the siding under the window but I measured the amount of play in the center and found it only to be about 1/16-inch and not the quarter-inch I thought it was. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: 1/16" might be as good as it gets; everything flexes a little. If you really don't like it, take off the vinyl and see if you can do something about it- but it's likely that it might not be easily improved. Possible options: 1. replace it with a solid double window. 2. Remove the window and put a bead of construction adhesive around it. 3. Expand the opening of the window and separate the windows (put a 2x4 between). 4. Less invasively, you might be able to drill a few port holes that will be hidden by the vinyl, where you could add glue. 5. Or you might be able to add some screws, afterall.

Comment: My only real concern, then, is that the windows need to be caulked and that amount of play will cause it to pull away from the caulk.

Comment: @rob caulk is kind of stiff, which might help hold it still. Silicone lasts about twice as long, but it's flexible. Construction adhesive (glue) will last about the same amounf of time as silicone and be a little more stiff. Silicone is easier to scrape off than glue, Caulk should be easiest for removal and replacement. SO, if you can add screws that might work better. I would probably go with silicone for sealing gaps. Again, there might not be an easy way to shore up this window. Consider replacement or separating the windows if it's a problem.

Comment: Silicone might be the best solution. I definitely won't be replacing the windows. The siding is inconveniently placed enough that I'm not going to mess with checking how well it's screwed/nailed in. At least not right now. And I just don't like the idea of gluing it in. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @rob Actually, I forgot a possibility, to put screws straight down into the sill, maybe beneath the window sash. Look carefully at the bottom of the window (under the sash or tucked away in the top and bottom of the channels). Look to see if there were _supposed_ to be screws there (which are missing)... it depends on how the window was built, exactly. Or (if not) and if you don't care about the window, you could (maybe) drill holes and sink screws into it. To be honest, **this might result in it's own set of problems**, and I would only recommend it if the circumstances were like F*** it.